# Drawing a One dimenstional contour plot for a potential field with respect to distance and velocity

Tags: matlab, plot, simulink, contour

I have the following code for the potential field

```
function PF = BRF (d, vi)
 a = 1;
 G =1;

      if ( vi <= 0 ) 
         dres = d + (vi*vi) / (2*a ) ; 
         else 
         dres = d - (vi*vi) / (2*a ); 
      end


      if(dres <= 0|| ((1+vi)/dres >= 1/G))
          PF = 1 ; 
      else if ((1+vi)/dres <=0)
          PF = 0 ; 
          else
          PF = G * ( (1+vi)/dres); 
          end 
      end
 end
```

The function depend on the velocity and the distance from the vehicle and the obstacle.

I have this code in a Matlab function block in a simulink model. I am taking the values of the distance from the simulink model to the workspace as well as the potential field and the velocity.

Now in the workspace I have a matrix of n*1 for all the potential field, distance and velocity.

How to draw the 1D contour for the potential field with respect to the distance and velocity?

a screenshot of the model is the following 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you probably want an [X-Y Graph block](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/xygraph.html), although it's not clear from your question why you are using Simulink and not simply MATLAB for this. Remember that in Simulink, everything is time-based so your workspace values need to be a function of time (for more details, see the doc on the [From Workspace](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block).

If this doesn't answer your question, can you post a screenshot of your model, provide more details and clarify your question?

Comment: I am taking the values to wark space as array therefore I am having it as n*1 values.. I provided a screenshot to the question.

Comment: and no I am not plotting an XY Graph.. I want to draw a 1 Dimentional contour.

Comment: Yes, that's what an X-Y Graph is... e.g. potential vs distance or potential vs velocity. Again, your question isn't clear, and I still don't see why you use Simulink, and not MATLAB for this.

Comment: this is a subblock.. I have more complicated system.. I will try the X,Y graph but I want the contour because I will integrate the system to 2 and 3 D later.